# How to Style XML with CSS?

Tags: css, xml, frontend

Im just trying to figure out how to style this XML code, however the xml is a URL and I'm trying to figure out how I would style this, does anyone have any idea? heres the XML example I'm trying to style:

```
<ListOfItems>
    <Product Name="The Fifth Dreamshaker Jumpsuit" Manufacturer="The Fifth" Url="http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/uk/catalog/productdetail.jsp?currency=200002&id=5129441181003" SKU="5129441181003">
    <Description>
    <![CDATA[
    <p>This jumpsuit is presented by casual-cool Australian label The Fifth and is the absolute pinnacle of casual-cool style thanks to its simple, clean lines and luxe-looking fabric.&nbsp; <br/><br/><strong>THINGS TO KNOW:</strong><br/>- Machine wash</p>
     <p><strong>SIZE &amp; FIT:</strong><br/>- Model wears: Small<br/>- Model height: 172.5cm/5'8</p>
    ]]>
    </Description>
    <Categories>
    <Category Name="women's>New>Clothing"/>
    <Category Name="women's>Dresses>Playsuits & Jumpsuits"/>
    </Categories>
    <Variations>
    <Variation Color="NAVY">
    <Images>
    <Image Url="http://euimages.urbanoutfitters.com/is/image/UrbanOutfittersEU/5129441181003_041_b?$zoom$&defaultImage="/>
    <Image Url="http://euimages.urbanoutfitters.com/is/image/UrbanOutfittersEU/5129441181003_041_d?$zoom$&defaultImage="/>
    <Image Url="http://euimages.urbanoutfitters.com/is/image/UrbanOutfittersEU/5129441181003_041_e?$zoom$&defaultImage="/>
    <Image Url="http://euimages.urbanoutfitters.com/is/image/UrbanOutfittersEU/5129441181003_041_f?$zoom$&defaultImage="/>
    <Image Url="http://euimages.urbanoutfitters.com/is/image/UrbanOutfittersEU/5129441181003_041_g?$zoom$&defaultImage="/>
    </Images>
    <Sizes>
    <Size Name="ONE SIZE" InStock="0" PriceGBP="84.00" OldPriceGBP="84.00" PriceEUR="115.00" OldPriceEUR="115.00"/>
    <Size Name="XS" InStock="1" PriceGBP="84.00" OldPriceGBP="84.00" PriceEUR="115.00" OldPriceEUR="115.00"/>
    <Size Name="S" InStock="1" PriceGBP="84.00" OldPriceGBP="84.00" PriceEUR="115.00" OldPriceEUR="115.00"/>
    <Size Name="M" InStock="1" PriceGBP="84.00" OldPriceGBP="84.00" PriceEUR="115.00" OldPriceEUR="115.00"/>
    <Size Name="L" InStock="1" PriceGBP="84.00" OldPriceGBP="84.00" PriceEUR="115.00" OldPriceEUR="115.00"/>
    </Sizes>
    </Variation>
    </Variations>
    </Product>
</ListOfItems>
```

Comment: Do you mean _how to present this XML in a visual manner_ for the final user?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i mean. Do you have any idea in how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Yes: The proper way to do it is through a _transformation sheet_ in XSL: You'll have to learn first the XSL transformation language, to transform your XML into an HTML page, and then you'll be able to apply CSS.

Comment: I agree that using XSLT to transform your XML to HTML with CSS is usually the better option. You can style pure XML with CSS as well but as your XML is very attribute centric styling with CSS will not show the data.